# Gtk# example to make an EventBox transparent

Tags: c#, mono, gtk, transparency, cairo

I need to create an image with transparency placed on top of another image, inside a regular Gtk# window. The first image should be able to respond to mouse clicks.

The simple way would usually be to put an Image inside an EventBox - and inside the window. However, EventBox is not transparent by default, so even if the png Image itself has transparent areas, when inside the EventBox it shows as a square opaque background around the image.

I'm aware that EventBox can be made transparent using **Cairo**, but so far was not able to do that.

**Can anyone provide a short C# example to make EventBox transparent?**

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! This is a programming question, which is off topic here. I voted to move it to Stack Overflow, so you should not need to create a question there as well. Superuser is more for general computer use and troubleshooting in a home environment, whereas Stack Overflow is for programming questions

Comment: As a temporary solution I use Cairo to create a PNG file and 'paint' all the transparent images to that PNG file, and then load the resulted PNG file back into one single event box. Although crude, it works. But I would still appreciate the obvious solution - having the EventBox be transparent, so all images could be loaded (from resources) each to an EventBox and displayed on the screen. Suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question...:

The solution is so simple, while I was looking for complex code to redraw the widget...
All that needs to be done is to set the EventBox.VisibleWindow member to 'false' (it is 'true' by default). Than the EventBox is not drawn and if the image inside the EventBox has transparent areas, they will show what ever is below.

In the example below, it is:
**mapBox.VisibleWindow = false;**
and
**pinBox.VisibleWindow = false;**

As far as I could see, the Z-Order (which Widget is on top of which) is determined by the order of drawing on the screen (when the EventBox is not drawn, the EventBox.GdkWindow.Lower() or Raised() members are not doing anything).

Example:

```
// Showing a map in an invisible EventBox
EventBox mapBox = new EventBox();
mapBox.Visible = true;
mapBox.VisibleWindow = false;
fixed1.Add(mapBox);
fixed1.Move (mapBox, 0, 0);

Image mapImage = new Image("map.png");
mapImage.Visible = true;
mapBox.Add (mapImage);

// Showing a pin image with transparent areas, in an invisible EventBox, on top of the map
EventBox pinBox = new EventBox();
pinBox.Visible = true;
pinBox.VisibleWindow = false;
fixed1.Add(pinBox);
fixed1.Move (pinBox, 60, 60);

Image pinImage = new Image("redpin.png");
pinImage.Visible = true;
pinBox.Add (pinImage);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) pygtk version would be `event_box.set_visible_window(False)`